# Categorical data analysis

Tags: statistics

Consider loglinear model for a $2\times2\times2$ table with $3$ categorical variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Assume mutual independence of these $3$ variables.

(a) Express the model in the form of $\log\mu = Xβ$.

(b) Write down the likelihood equation of this model and show that it equates $\{nijk\}$ and $\{\mu ijk\}$ in the one-dimensional margins.